# Chat room doesn't exist?

Tags: discussion, chat

Chat rooms are referenced here -- https://diy.stackexchange.com/privileges/chat-rooms

Yet when I try visiting the url (http://chat.diy.stackexchange.com), I get an error.  Is this working for anyone?

-M

Answer (score 2):

Chat hasn't been rolled out for every site yet.

Assuming the site graduates - which isn't certain given the figures on [our Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/170/home-improvement) - then chat will be added.

The privileges page is the same template for all sites, but with different values depending on where the site is in the process.

Comment: It seems a bit unfair to compare DIY to many of the other sites.  I can ship a dozen software applications before I finish remodeling a single bedroom.

Comment: @Steve - Agreed. I think that the fact the site has survived this long means that Jeff & Joel see some value in it. I haven't seen any feedback indicating it might be closed so who knows.

Comment: Related for those that don't hang out there: [this question on MSO](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/68079/146318).

Comment: @Niall - thanks for that link. Joel's comment is particularly important - vote folks, **vote**.