# Has anyone else had intermittent spurts of across-the-board upvotes?

Tags: discussion

Today, for the second time in the last week or so, I've had a windfall of upvotes -- upwards of a dozen at a time.  Each time all the votes have been within a few minutes of each other, which leads me to believe the same person is upvoting a bunch of my answers in the same session.  Maybe I'm just looking a gift horse in the mouth and someone liked one of my answers enough to go through and upvote many others, but it seems a little fishy.  Is anyone else seeing this kind of thing?

Comment: Could be someone's trying to push you into the 3k+ category to boost the site stats on Area51. Not exactly the purpose of upvoting, but if you've got good answers then it's justified. I recently went back through the users hovering just below 200 rep and upvoted any good answers/questions they had. I figured it would encourage them to contribute more and also boost site stats.

Comment: @Doresoom Ah, a conspiracy!

Answer (score 6):

I wasn't responsible today, but I did spend a couple days a week or two ago trying to find interesting questions and answers to max out my votes for the day.  Mostly in response to [this](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/176/chat-room-doesnt-exist) and [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68079/please-do-not-close-gis-se) and [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/10/vote-early-vote-often/).  You often have excellent answers, so if anyone else was doing the same I wouldn't be surprised if you were bumped.

Comment: Thanks Steve -- that makes sense.  I haven't been voting as much as I should!

Answer (score 2):

I checked your upvotes and I do not see anything suspicious; just a bunch of votes from known users.  We did have another user report the same thing but I searched and could not find anything suspicious at that time either.

I know my usage of this site is similar to @Steve Jackson's.  I come in and read through new questions and vote up the good answers and questions in one session.  So that type of usage (and I bet that is a similar pattern for others) could explain why you got a bunch of upvotes all at once.

Comment: I was that user and the up-votes I got triggered the vote fraud scripts so they were rescinded. It was no big thing as I had some other votes that day and soon regained the rep, but I did get a couple of badges from the votes which I've only just re-earned.